# from same axios to different components, VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

Okay, I have two different components and each of those get Axios response. But I don't want to fetch data in each component separate. That's is not right, and it cause components run separate...

### Updated 3

I did some changes on the code, but still having some problems. I am doing axios call with Vuex in `Store.js` and import it into my component. it's like below.

This is my store.js component;

```html
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

var actions = _buildActions();
var modules = {};
var mutations = _buildMutations();

const state = {
    storedData: []
};

Vue.use(Vuex);

const getters = {
    storedData: function(state) {
        return state.storedData;
    }
};

function _buildActions() {
    return {
        fetchData({ commit }) {
            axios
                .get("/ajax")
                .then(response => {
                    commit("SET_DATA", response.data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    commit("SET_ERROR", error);
                });
        }
    };
}

function _buildMutations() {
    return {
        SET_DATA(state, payload) {
            console.log("payload", payload);
            const postData = payload.filter(post => post.userId == 1);
            state.storedData = postData;
        }
    };
}

export default new Vuex.Store({
    actions: actions,
    modules: modules,
    mutations: mutations,
    state: state,
    getters
});
```

Now importing it into `Average` component.

```html
import store from './Store.js';

export default {
    name:'average',
    data(){
        return{
            avg:"",
            storedData: [],
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        console.log(this.$store)
        this.$store.dispatch('fetchDatas')
        this.storedData = this.$store.dispatch('fetchData')
    },
    methods: {
        avgArray: function (region) {
             const sum = arr => arr.reduce((a,c) => (a += c),0);
             const avg = arr => sum(arr) / arr.length;

             return avg(region);
        },
    },
    computed: {
        mapGetters(["storedData"])

        groupedPricesByRegion () {
         return this.storedData.reduce((acc, obj) => {
                var key = obj.region;
                if (!acc[key]) {
                    acc[key] = [];
                }
                acc[key].push(obj.m2_price);
                return acc;
            }, {});
        },

        averagesByRegion () {
         let arr = [];
            Object.entries(this.groupedPricesByRegion)
                .forEach(([key, value]) => {
                    arr.push({ [key]: Math.round(this.avgArray(value)) });
            });
            return arr;
        },
    }
}
```

I can see the data stored in the console. But there are errors too. I can't properly pass the data in `myComponent`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6mlV.png

Comment: Use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/). And replace axios into services and use them in vuex stores.

Comment: if these two components use same component use vuex instead

Comment: @Alexander could you please check the question out, I used vuex but having some problem.

Comment: I guess, You've not injected your store in main app as `Vue.use(store)`.

Comment: you mean `myComponent` do I need to use this `Vue.use(store)` in myComponent? @varit05

Comment: @Barbie I've created [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kxq40pp0q7) demo with Vue + Vuex. Let me know if you need explanation. There are a lot of places where you need to modified code if you want to use state management. and you don't need to use it `Vue.use(store)` at component level. it has to be at app level.

Comment: @Barbie Inside your Vue Instance add the `store` so It will be available at the component level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that 
To resolve the error you're getting, Below are the steps.

Import your store file inside the file where your Vue Instance is initialized.

```
// Assuming your store file is at the same level
import store from './store';
```

Inside your, Add store object inside your Vue Instance

```
function initApp(appNode) {
    new Vue({
        el: appNode,
        router: Router,
        store // ES6 sytax
    });
}
```

There you go, you can now access your store from any component.

UPDATE: For Second Error

Instead of changing data inside your component, change it inside `mutation` in the store because you do not want to write the same login in other components where the same method is used.

Hence,

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["storedData"]),
    anotherFunction() {
       // Function implementation.
    }
}
```

Inside your mutation set the data.

```
SET_DATA(state, payload) {
    console.log("payload", payload);
    state.storedData = payload;
}
```

Inside getters, you can perform what you were performing inside your computed properties.

```
storedData: function(state) {
    const postData = state.storedData.filter(post => post.userId == 1);
    return postData;
}
```

Vuex Official [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html)

> Here is the working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kxq40pp0q7)

Hope this helps!

Comment: first, thank you for helping me out. It's really make me crazy! Okay, I checked out the sandbox you created and recreated my `store.js` like in the sandbox. But i am a bit confused(it's my lack of knowledge sorry about that) so I updated the the code in the question with new errors. check it out please, thank you.

Comment: You can not directly mutate data inside your component hence if you need your data to use reduce use `mutations` and filter your data inside it instead of doing it in computed properties. You do not want to write same login inside all the component which are using your `fetchData` method. Change computed properties as I have did it codesandbox, plus add `getters` inside your store.

Comment: thank you for the update, the part i didn't get is how to add this part `mapGetters(["storedData"])` into my computed at average component, I updated the code... because it's says  `mapGetters is not defined` when I added it

Comment: You need to remove `storeData` from your Average component except `mapGetters(["storedData"])` as redux store state is also reactive just as vue data. Now you do not need `groupedPricesByRegion` function as it is moved to store. you can move `averageByRegion` function to the `getters` function. Please accept and upvote the answer if it helps you to resolve your asked question.

Comment: If you want to use another function with `mapgetters(['fetchData'])`. please use it as a object.

Comment: One small correction, instead of changing data inside mutation, you can change it inside `getters`. It was my bad. I've updated the example and answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want use vuex to distrib data maybe you can try eventBus, when you get data form the axios respose @emit the event and in another component @on this event